# varnish compilation fails on or statement

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to allow logins on my site. So I setup the following in my VCL under varnish 4:

```
# Allow the beta site to login
   if ( req.http.host ~ "^beta\.example\.com$" && req.url ~ "^?oa_social_login_source=custom$" ) {
      return (pass);
   }
```

But when I go to do a syntax check on the VCL I get the following error:

```
#varnishd -C -f default.vcl
Message from VCC-compiler:
Regexp compilation error:

nothing to repeat

('input' Line 111 Pos 62)
   if ( req.http.host ~ "^beta\.example\.com$" && req.url ~ "^?oa_social_login_source=custom$" ) {
-------------------------------------------------------------##################################----

Running VCC-compiler failed, exited with 2

VCL compilation failed
```

Can anybody help me out with the syntax on what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the question mark - as that is regexp quantifier sign.

`req.url ~ "^\?oa_social_login_source=custom$"`